# How to concatenate 2 same-table queries results keeping a unique key in SQLite?

Tags: sql, sqlite

Considering the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE `foo`(
  `aaa` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `bbb` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `ccc` INT NOT NULL,
  `ddd` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY(`aaa`, `bbb`, `ccc`)
);
```

the following data:

```
INSERT INTO `foo` (`aaa`, `bbb`, `ccc`, `ddd`)
VALUES
('qwe', 'rty', 0, 123),
('asd', 'fgh', 0, 456),
('asd', 'fgh', 1, 678);
```

the following result is to be gotten:

```
'qwe', 'rty', 0, 123
'asd', 'fgh', 1, 678
```

The objective is to get

- Only one record for each (`aaa`, `bbb`) keypair
- Favour records with `ccc` = 1 if there are more than 1 record for a (`aaa`, `bbb`) keypair in the table

So I think I need to concatenate result sets of 2 queries:

```
SELECT * FROM `foo` WHERE `ccc` = 1
```

and

```
SELECT * FROM `foo` WHERE `ccc` = 0
```

discarding a second query result row when there is already a same (`aaa`, `bbb`) keypair row in the first query result.

How to code it in SQLite?

Comment: Doesn't SQLite allow `IN` clause, as in `ccc IN (0, 1)`? If it does, then you can rewrite your query as `SELECT DISTINCT aaa, bbb FROM foo WHERE ccc IN (0, 1)`.

Comment: @Vikdor I am not sure if it does support this, will try, but I need full records and only the record with ccc=1 if both ccc=1 and ccc=0 versions of the same record exist, I doubt your query does that (maybe it does though, I haven't had any SQLite experience before this).

Comment: you can merely do it by joining a subquery which has the maximum value for each `aaa` and `bbb`. see my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one,

```
SELECT  a.*
FROM    foo a
        INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT  aaa, bbb, MAX(ccc) maxC
            FROM foo
            GROUP BY aaa, bbb
        ) b ON a.aaa = b.aaa AND
                a.ccc = b.maxC AND
                a.bbb = b.bbb
```

## [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/0b317/2)

Comment: Seems working, @john-woo. Let's see how is it going to go on big data (the real database is going to be about 1.5 GiB). I was always thinking that JOIN is meant to concatenate tables horizontally (combine columns from different tables in a wider table in the result), didn't know it also does vertical. By the way, trying to understand the query, I can't get how is `b` defined: jou just join the query result with some mysterious `b` and address `b`'s columns but how do we get that `b`?

Comment: the subquery which I named `b` gets the maximum value of `ccc` for every pair of `aaa` and `bbb`. after it gets the maximum, it then join to the original table provided that the columns `aaa`, `bbb`, and with the newly found max value of `ccc` must match all conditions. try running the subquery only and see what the results are :D

Comment: Oh, I see now, `b` is defined in the parentheses before it.